# Getting React Native ScrollView scale or scaled dimensions

Tags: javascript, react-native

Is there a way to reference the current dimensions or scale of a zoomed ScrollView? The documentation mentions zoomScale but that's returning as undefined.

I've tried the following so far:

```
onScrollUpdate() {
    console.log(this.refs.pageScrollView.zoomScale); // returns undefined
    RCTUIManager.measure(findNodeHandle(this.refs.pageScrollView), (x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
    console.log(width); // returns initial size, but not scaled - this number change when zooming
  });
 }
<ScrollView
    ref='pageScrollView'
    onScroll={this.onScrollUpdate.bind(this)}
    minimumZoomScale={0.95}
    maximumZoomScale={2}
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    scrollEventThrottle={2}
  >
```

Answer (score 0):

[Solution moved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309552/997587) from [@EmmaWilliams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7562744/emma-williams)' question post.

> The onScroll event receives a nativeEvent which includes zoomScale amount:
>
> ```
> onScrollUpdate(event) {
>     console.log(event.nativeEvent.zoomScale)  // returns accurate zoomscale
> }
> ```